# react scroll top при переходе от страниц

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Каждый раз при переходе на новую страницу скролл остается внизу. Как сделать чтобы каждом переходе на новую страницу скролл был сверху?

Вот [ссылка на проект](https://ezkahan.site)

Answer (score 0):

Я не специалист по ReactJS, но попробуйте на роутере повесить событие, после перехода на страницу вызывайте `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`.

Так же можно скролить страницу плавно:

```
document.body.scrollIntoView({
    block: "start", 
    behavior: "smooth",
});
```

Но, не смотря на анимацию, думаю, простой `scrollTo` будет лучше.